# cut string to get linux time

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

```
DESCRIPTION:When: ‎יום שלישי 28 אוקטובר 2014 10:00 עד 11
```

I would like to cut the text in order to convert the dat to linux time date

how do I get the 28 (day) , אוקטובר  (month), and 2014 (year), 10:00 (time)  with regular expression ?

Is there any better way?

Comment: Check [PHP's strptime](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to extract all numeric value using preg_match then concat as per your need.

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $yourString, $matches);

echo $dateTime = $matches[0][2].':'.$matches[0][3].' '.$matches[0][0].'-'.$matches[0][4].'-'.$matches[0][1];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
exit;
```